# How to see Logs of exceptions?

Tags: logs, exceptions

I'm using solidity compiler ^0.4.23, I added logs to the function at exception points like this:

```
function firstSaleDelivery(address _beneficiary, uint256 rate) public onlyOwner{
  require(!presaleOpen && !firstsaleOpen, "First Sale is NOT CLOSE");
  if(preSaleTokens >= 0){
      saleTokens = saleTokens.add(preSaleTokens);
      preSaleTokens = 0;
  }
  uint256 ethers = firstSaleFunds[_beneficiary];
  uint256 tokens = ethers.mul(rate);    // <u>
  require(saleTokens >= tokens, "NO Sale Tokens Available");
  if(ethers >= 5 && ethers <= 9 ){
    tokens.add((tokens.mul(10)).div(100));            // <u>
  }
  else if(ethers >= 10 && ethers <= 200 ){
    tokens.add((tokens.mul(25)).div(100));            // <u>
  }
  token.transfer(_beneficiary,tokens);
  saleTokens = saleTokens.sub(tokens);
```

}

When I invoke the function, and if I face any exception, I can't see these Logs, where I can see them?

Comment: you can use remix to debug your code

Comment: I don't want it for debugging purpose, I want my users of contract know why their transaction has failed.

Comment: so make it a bool function which returns false when it fails!!

Comment: Returning a `false` doesn't really say anything about *why* it failed..

Comment: Yes, my purpose is to let users know about WHY it failed,

Comment: as a trick you can use only if else with events instead require. but you can't return to users the exception cause as the execution is reverted.

Answer (score 1):

Logs are not produced if the transaction reverts (see this answer: [Is it possible to retrieve an event log from a reverted transaction?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/38019/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-an-event-log-from-a-reverted-transaction)).

Comment: Despite the misleading title, the question is not about events.

Comment: Oh. Should I remove the answer?  I don’t know the etiquette.

Answer (score 1):

The reason string is a very new addition to `revert` and `require` (about one week old). I believe that Geth's DebugTrace exposes the reason string, but otherwise I'm not sure there's tooling support yet.

I imagine that soon enough Etherscan will just surface them, but at the moment, reason strings are not particularly accessible to end users.

Comment: As I understand, if there is an exceptition, the TX is never mined and so it will never be present on Etherscan. Is that correct?

Comment: No, that's incorrect. Transactions that revert are still mined and still cost gas.

Comment: Here's a recent transaction that reverted: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9f00a37416a64735b02ab76da4477ea297bfd4923b1564c1b3579d542b3f4071.